# Converting character array to Floating Point with 2 Decimal Places

Tags: c, floating-point

I have defined a character array like this.

```
char pkgamount[20]="";
```

This can be populated by values like 120, -120, -120.23 etc (Up to 2 decimal places)

I currently convert the char array to integer like this.

```
    int amt2;
    sscanf(pkgamount, "%d", &amt2);
```

What is the proper way to convert the character array that can containing negative decimals to a float value with only 2 decimal places?

**UPDATE: #1**

I read values from a database (VARCHAR) to the character array.These value will have a maximum of 2 decimal places.The value can be 0/With 2 decimal places/with no decimal places at all. I think integer data type cannot have decimal places. I need to add/subtract these values.So I need to convert the character array to float.

**UPDATE #2**

I tried using float and I keep getting some random output.Please the extracted code below

```
float bamt1,bamt2,amt1,amt2;
float balance1,balance2;
sscanf(stbamount, "%f", &amt1);
sscanf(pkgamount, "%f", &amt2);
//amoun1=32 amount2=23 any decimal or non decimal values..using API  
//Using API on device to read this..skipping the code for that
sscanf(amount1, "%f", &bamt1);
sscanf(amount2, "%f", &bamt2);
balance1=amt1-bamt1;
balance2=amt2-bamt2;
// buffers used for conversion and printing 
char buf1[sizeof(int)*3+2]="";
snprintf(buf1, sizeof buf1, "%f", balance1);
char buf2[sizeof(int)*3+2]="";
char sbal[20]="";
char pbal[20]="";
strcat(sbal,"STB Balance: ");
strcat(pbal,"PKG Balance: ");
strcat(sbal,buf1);
strcat(pbal,buf2);     
//prn_write_text is API Call to run thermal printer on device 
prn_write_text(sbal,strlen(sbal),1);       
prn_write_text(pbal,strlen(pbal),1);   
snprintf(buf2, sizeof buf2, "%f", balance2);
```

**UPDATE #3**

This is the API Call to use the thermal printer to write some text. I need to convert the floating point value to a string and cut it, so that it includes only 2 decimal values.

[image]

Comment: Note: `double` and `float` have too little chance to have *only* 2 decimal places except for some special numbers, so they won't suit for this.

Comment: @MikeCAT Thanks but the values i will be processing will have a maximum of 2 decimal places.What do you recommend?

Comment: What is your problem? Do you want to truncate decimal places, so that 3.33333 is evaluated as 3.33? Depending on what you want to do, you might be better off representing your numbers as integers. For example if 120.23 is an amount in dollers, store it as the amount in cents, 12023.

Comment: Are the numbers and floats mixed up in the char array? Is there any other way that you use to find out if it is a number or a float?

Comment: @MOehm I read values from a database(VARCHAR) to the character array.These value will have a maximum of 2 decimal places.I think integer data type cannot have decimal places.I need to add/subtract these values.So i need to convert the character array to float.

Comment: @RishikeshRaje Please see the above comment.The value can be 0/With 2 decimal places/with no decimal places at all.

Comment: No, you don't need to convert your numbers to float. As Mike said, most of the floating-point numbers with two decimal places (inn fact all except 0.25, 0.50 and 0.75) can't be represented exactly by floats. When you treat the numbers as fixed-point numbers, essentially integers with a fixed denominator of 100, your summations will be exact.

Comment: @MOehm So i simply use `int` datatype and use the above approach? Can you give an example?

Comment: @techno - do you need accuracy of 0.00 during addition or subtraction, or can you live with possible errors of 0.01. This will decide what type you should use. If it is the former, you need to use integers as mentioned by M Oehm, otherwise floats will serve your purpose.

Comment: @RishikeshRaje Well it would be okay.But i personally dont want to write buggy code.

Comment: @techno its up to you how you store your values. As @MOehm told you, you can always store your values as integers and define that all those integers hold 100 times the real value. You can later simply convert the integer to a float by `float x = (float)int_value / 100.0`. Just check the position of the decimal point (if any) and multiply the resulting output: For "123", no decimal dot => Multiply by 100, for "123.4" => Multiply by 10, "123.45" => just store the integer without multiplication.

Comment: @techno: It's not buggy code. Whether floats are okay depends on what you want to do. But have yiou tried using floats? Do you run into accuracy problems? And is your question really how to scan floats with `sscanf`?

Comment: @MOehm I have tried using floats and it prints some random data.

Comment: @MOehm Please see update #2

Comment: @ikrabbe Please see update#2 to see my current approach using floats.

Comment: Hmm, looks good, provided that the inputstrings are good. You don't check whether a conversion actually takes place. (`sscanf` returns the number of conversions made, which should be 1 in your case.) Check your conversion for errors. Another issue might ba a locale the excepcts, fo example, a comme instead of a decimal point.

Comment: @MOehm Input strings are good.But i keep getting some random value as `STB Balance` and `PKG Balance`

Comment: Voting to close... Unfortunately the current [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is neither m nor c nor v.

Comment: for `PKG Balance` you are writing to `buf2` after `strcat(pbal,buf2); `

Comment: "Input strings are good" I have only your word for that. What does the program say? (In other words: Add error-checking and meaningful error messages to your code and you might find the error. To me, "Random value" suggests that no conversion has taken place and the float isn't initialised.)

Comment: @MOehm I tried printing out the float values that are getting converted from the character array.But some error in conversion produces invalid output.amt1 should be 50.50 and amt2 should be -180.52.           `amount1 ---------->1078542336
amount2 ---------->-1067020125
balance1 ---------->1077641216
balance2 ---------->-1066561373`

Comment: Please, don't provide information piecemeal. Create a minimal compilable example, like `float f; char *s = "50.50"; sscanf(s, "%f", &f); printf("'%s': %f\n", s, f);` and if that shows erroneous behaviour, we can help you. At the moment, we can only guess, which is very tedious.

Comment: @MOehm I tried debugging again .. and fixed some code.The calculations are all correct now(am1,amt2,balance1,balance2).The issue come where i convert the float to a character array for printing(using the API Call to Thermal Printer-It only accepts character array). This is the line of code that causes the issue `char buf1[sizeof(int)*3+2]="";
    snprintf(buf1, sizeof buf1, "%f", balance1); ` ...what do you think?

Comment: @MOehm Please see update #3

Comment: You should use `"%.2f" to print floats with 2 decimal chars. Otherwise you will get a lot of characters in output.

Comment: @RishikeshRaje But i need to copy this float to a character pointer/array.How can i do it?

Answer (score 1):

Using floats to store the numbers..

```
float amtf;
sscanf(pkgamount, "%f", &amtf);
```

To print the numbers to 2 decimal places

```
printf (".2%f",amtf);
```

You can use floats to store the numbers as long as you are willing to tolerate errors of possibly 0.01 during addition or subtraction. It makes the code easier.

However, if you absolutely have to be accurate down to the last 0.00 then you should use integers * 100 to store the data, as suggested by M Oehem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.Can you please take a look at my update #2

Answer (score 1):

Just loop through your characters

```
enum parseFloatErrorCodes {
    SUCCESS, DOUBLE_DOT,PARSE_ERROR, INTEGER_OVERFLOW,
    TOO_MANY_DIGITS_AFTER_DECIMAL_POINT
};
int parse_float(char* inp, float *x) { 
    char *p;
    int ival, dot;
    for (ival = 0, dot = 0, p = inp; *p; ++p) {
        int overflow_check = ival;
        if (('0' <= *p) && (*p <= '9')) {
            ival = ival * 10 + (int)(*p - '0');
            if (dot > 0) ++dot;
        } else if (*p == '.') {
            if (dot > 0) { return DOUBLE_DOT; }
            dot = 1;
        } else { return PARSE_ERROR; }
        if (overflow_check > ival) { return INTEGER_OVERFLOW; }
    }
    *x = ival;
    if (dot == 0) *x *= 100.0;
    else if (dot == 1) *x *= 100.0;
    else if (dot == 2) *x *= 10.0;
    else if (dot > 3) { return TOO_MANY_DIGITS_AFTER_DECIMAL_POINT; }
    *x /= 100.0;
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

See the [gist](https://gist.github.com/ikrabbe/94df85203ace95542ba8) for test code that works.

Comment: You have specified `char* inp` as a pointer,but in my case input will be a character array.

Comment: any char buf[N] will be acceptable as input to parse_float, as long as your buffer is `\0` terminated.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/ikrabbe/94df85203ace95542ba8 This is the corrected function with test code (see the comment for output).

Comment: And before someone tells me why to write an own function: The own function can return exactly the parse errors you want, with regards to the input.

Comment: Overflow check is too late.  Should `ival = ival * 10 + (int)(*p - '0');` overflow, the result is undefined behavior.  Better to stay with unsigned integers which does not have this problem.  Recommend `unsigned long long ival, overflow_check;`.  BTW cast `(int)` not needed.

Comment: I don't want that long values, and the behaviour is not that undefined but an positive integer simply flips to values <0 when the overflow condition is reached, which is enough for my overflow test. The cast is not needed but clarifies what happens.

Comment: @ikrabbe Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36082408/cut-long-float-value-to-2-decimal-points-and-copy-to-character-array/36082622#36082622

Comment: and what should I see there? The own function is shorter but still works better for the use case.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE #2 writes outside the the character array. --> UB

Assume `sizeof(int)== 4` or `8`.

```
// buf1[14] or buf1[26]
char buf1[sizeof(int)*3+2]="";

// the string length of buf1 is at least 8 and likely 10+
snprintf(buf1, sizeof buf1, "%f", balance1);

char sbal[20]="";
strcat(sbal,"STB Balance: ");  // 14 char used

// attempts to write at least 14+8 = 22 char, sbal too small.  
strcat(sbal,buf1);
```

Perhaps OP wants

```
#include <float.h>
//                     -    Digits in FLT_MAX     .xx      \0
#define FLT_SIZE_2_DP (1 + (FLT_MAX_10_EXP + 1) + (1 + 2) + 1 

char sbal[sizeof("STB Balance: ") + FLT_SIZE_2_DP];
int len = snprintf(sbal, sizeof sbal, "STB Balance: %.2f", balance1);
if (len >= 0 && len < sizeof sbal) {
  prn_write_text(sbal,strlen(sbal),1);       
else {
  prn_write_text("Error",5,1);       
}
```

---

> What is the proper way to convert the character array that can containing negative decimals to a float value with only 2 decimal places?

When code has a special input require, useful to create a helper function to meet the need.  The below reads 2 integers and then combines them into a `float`.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// EOF: end-of-file or IO error
// 0: no conversion
// 1: success
int read_float_2dp(FILE *istream, float *f) {
  intmax_t ipart;
  char fpart_str[3];
  int count = fscanf(istream, "%jd.%2[0-9]", &ipart, fpart_str);
  if (count <= 0) return count;
  int fpart = (count == 2) ? atoi(fpart_str) : 0;
  if (ipart < 0) fpart = -fpart;
  *f = ipart + fpart / 100.0f;
  return 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks.. This is what i was looking for.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36082408/cut-long-float-value-to-2-decimal-points-and-copy-to-character-array/36082622#36082622. I will take a detailed look at your answer and get back tomorrow.

Comment: @techno Is the question/answer still needing attention?

Comment: I have upvoted your answer.Abandoned project.. so dont know which answer works.

Answer (score 0):

```
    char pkgamount[10],pkgamount1[10];
    char something[][3] = {"1.3","53","123","569"};
    int amt2;
    float amt1;
    sscanf(pkgamount,"%2d",&amt2);
    sscanf(pkgamount1,"%2.2f",&am1);
```

the %2d will only scan upto decimal values, same with the float 2 before decimal point and 2 after...Now the problem is i dont know exactly what yu are expecting, thats the reason i defined the something[][3] 2D array, cause thats how yu store values which means something[0][3] something[1][3] something[2][3] so on and so forth that in memory means that array something in place 0 can hold 3 chars, on place 1 can hold 3.....Now its upto yu how exactly yu use a loop to take in values... I can give yu an example..

```
    char something[10][3];
    int i;
    for (1..10)
    {
        scanf("%2s",&something[i]);
    }
    printf("\nSomething array");
    for (i..10)
    {
        printf("\n%2s",something[i]);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.Can you please take a look at my update #2

Comment: `sscanf(pkgamount1,"%2.2f",&am1);` has porblems.  1) What is ".2" about? 2) What is `am1`?  3) Code skipping to check the return value of `sscanf()`.