# Cut Long Float Value to 2 decimal points and copy to Character Array

Tags: c, floating-point

I need to convert a Long a Float Value to Character Array,i need to do this because the Device API Only accepts calls like this

[image]

I have something like this 200.56866 I need a value like 200.56.

I tried doing

```
    char buf1[sizeof(int)*3+2]="";
    snprintf(buf1, sizeof buf1, "%f", balance1);
```

But the conversion produces some random value.How can i do this properly?

EDIT:This question is not related to cutting off decimal values alone .. it mainly involves the issue of copying float to char array.

Comment: please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc The below answer solved this..... thanks anyway..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to cut decimal off without rounding in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12764009/how-to-cut-decimal-off-without-rounding-in-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the second line to `snprintf(buf1, sizeof buf1, "%.2f", balance1);`. Also, why do you declare the amount of storage to allocate your buffer with that particular expression?

**EDIT**
@LưuVĩnhPhúc mentioned in a comment below that the format specifier in my original answer will round instead of truncating so based on [How to cut decimal off without rounding in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12764009/how-to-cut-decimal-off-without-rounding-in-c) you could do the following:

```
float balance = 200.56866;
int tmp = balance1 * 100;
float balance1 = tmp / 100.0;
char buf1[sizeof(int)*3+2]="";
snprintf(buf1, sizeof buf1, "%.2f", balance1);
```

Comment: There was some issue.. i don't remember properly.Some answer on SO,Suggested doing that.. Should i remove it?

Comment: that will *round* the value, not truncate, so 200.56866 will become 200.57

Comment: @techno I just find that it's very specific and cryptic. I won't say to remove it without understanding why it's there in the first place. You just need to ensure that the buffer is large enough to store the representation of the entire float with an extra element to store the null character at the end or part could get cut off.

Comment: `why do you declare the amount of storage to allocate your buffer with that particular expression` I think he mean 3 decimal digits for each byte (as CHAR_MAX is 3 digits) and plus 1 for decimal point, 1 for null termination. But he forgot one byte for minus at the beginning

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc Actually i dont mean anything.. i really cannot remember why i did that..  may be because of random value issue.

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc I edited my answer to take your point on truncation into consideration and credited you. I'm a bit too tired now to understand your reasoning of the expression for the storage allocation but I'll think about it later.